# Class instance does not exist in this context (button of form class) c#

Tags: c#

I have created a new class called `Calculator`, saved in my project folder and I am wondering why I cannot call methods `SetPressure(double p)` for the instance `calculator1` from the `button_Click` method. I get an error saying that

> `calculator1 does not exist in this context.`

Sorry, it's probably an easy question regarding scope but i cannot find any appropriate answer elsewhere and I would appreciate some help a lot.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        Calculator calculator1 = new Calculator();
        // ...
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double pressure = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        //textBox6.Text = "pressure is" + pressure;
        calculator1.SetPressure(pressure);
    }
```

Comment: It's a local variable in `InitializeComponent()`. Make it a class member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I get an error saying that `calculator1` does not exist in this context.

That's right, `calculator1` is a local variable inside the `InitializeComponent()` method. You should initialize it as part of the `Form1`, either in the constructor, or in a field initializer:

```
private readonly Calculator calculator1 = new Calculator();

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    ... // Do not initialize calculator1 here, it's already initialized
}
```

Now all methods of `Form1` can share the same instance of `calculator1` without re-defining it separately in each method.

Answer (score 2):

because of the scope of variable you defined in the method `IntializeComponent` `Calculator calculator1 = new Calculator();` you are getting error.

> class Instance doesn't exist.

To solve your problem two options available.

**Option1.** create instance of Calucalator with in button_click method.

> ```
>  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>             {
>                 double pressure = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
>                 //textBox6.Text = "pressure is" + pressure;
>                 Calculator calculator1 = new Calculator();
>                 calculator1.SetPressure(pressure);
>             }
> ```

**Option2.** create class variable that would be available across Form1

```
        public partial class Form1:Form         
        private readonly Calculator calculator1 = new Calculator();    
        private void InitializeComponent()
                    {
                       }      
             private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        double pressure = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
                        //textBox6.Text = "pressure is" + pressure;
                        calculator1.SetPressure(pressure);
                    }
```

Comment: thanks that works, but I would like to have several buttons that can set different values for the same instance, so creating a new "Calculator" in each button_click method will not really help I guess?

Comment: you can try option i listed out in 2.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!